# NInject: Create an instance on the fly according to object instance class

Tags: c#, .net, ninject

I've these two interfaces and classes:

```
interface IViz<T> {
   R Accept<R>(IVizVisitor<T, R> visitor);
}
interface IGroupedViz<T, TKey> : IViz<T> {
   R Accept<R>(IGroupedVizVisitor<T, TKey, R> visitor);
}

class Viz<T> : IViz<T> {}
class GroupedViz<T, Tkey> : IGroupedViz<T, TKey> {}
```

I've also created two `visitor` interfaces:

```
interface IVizVisitor<T, R> {
    R Visit(IViz<T> viz);
}

interface IGroupedVizVisitor<T, TKey, R> : IVizVisitor<T, R> {
    R Visit(IGroupedViz<T, TKey> group);
    //...
}
```

So, I need to create an instance of `IVizVisitor<T>` or `IGroupedVizVisitor<T, TKey>` according to `IViz<T>` or `IGroupedViz<T,TKey>` instance.

Example:

```
static void Main(VizFactory vizFactory) {
    IList<IViz<MyT>> vizs = new List<IViz<MyT>>();
    vizs.add(new Viz<MyT>());
    vizs.add(new GroupedViz<T, string>());

    foreach (IViz<MyT> viz in vizs) {
      //(!!1!!)
      //IVizVisitor<MyT> visitor = vizFactory.GetVisitor(??????);
      //get an `IVizVisitor<T>` or an `IGroupedVizVisitor<T, TKey>`
      viz.Accept(visitor);
    }
}
```

I want to get on `(!!1!!)`:

1. A `IVizVisitor<T>` if `viz` is an instance of `IViz<T>`
2. A `IGroupedVizVisitor<T, TKey>` if `viz` is an instance of `IGroupedViz<T, TKey>`.

I want to get it using `NInject`. I guess I could get it using Ninject Factory, but I've not able to figure out how to get it...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can read about Ninject factory:

https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/wiki/Factory-interface

And I highly recommend to read also this article:

https://chodounsky.net/2014/01/29/dynamic-dispatch-in-c-number/